# hbase for storing gamers' last 1000 key hits

Tags: database, hbase

So for my use case, I need to save only the last 1000 key hits of each gamer. and there will be only 2 fields --> gamerId (all numeric) and keyId (also all numeric). so, lets say, gamer 1123 already has 999 keyIds stored, when the 1000th keyId comes in for that gamer, normal insertion. however, once 1001st keyId comes in, we need to remove the earliest recorded keyId for that gamer and persist that 1001st in. so, at all times, there can only be max 1000 keyIds for each gamer in the db. We have +/- 100 million of gamers and very high keyId traffic, and this table will be looked up and written into very frequently.
will HBase be suitable for this? if it's not, what could be the alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you can get this done in hbase very easily thanks to versioning. I've never tried something as extreme at 1,000 versions per column (normally 5-10) but I don't think there is any specific restriction as to how many versions you can have. You should just see if it creates any performance implications. Also check out this discussion: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-versions-for-an-HBase-cell

When you define your table and your column family, you can specify the max versions parameter. This way, when you simply keep doing the Puts with the same row value, the key for that row will keep generating new versions (they will all be time-stamped as well. Once you do your 1,001th Put, the 1st put will automatically be deleted, and so on on the FIFO basis. Similarly, when you do a Get on that row-key, you can use various methods to retrieve a range of versions. In that case it depends on what API you will be using to get the values (this is easy to do with native Java API, but not sure about other access methods).

100mln rows is quite small for HBase, so generally it shouldn't be a problem. But of course if each of your rows really has 1,000 versions, then you are looking at 100bln key-values. Again, I'd say it's doable for HBase, but you should see imperially whether this causes any performance problems and you should size your cluster appropriately.

Comment: for GET, we're always interested in the latest version only, we dont care about any other versions, we can even discard all the other versions except the latest one if possible. will that improve performance? or maybe enable certain config during HBase setup that can further improve performance?

Comment: You can use Get.readVersions(numVersions) to ensure that only one version is returned.

Comment: yeah, I guess at this point, room for speculation has been exhausted, actual benchmark testing is the only path moving forward now. But since fb messenger is also using hbase, I'm feeling pretty confident with hbase. thanks for the pointer!